# Swift3 different font in the All of the UIView with Localization each

Tags: swift, xcode, localization

I want to use different fonts up to Languages each.

for example, roboto in English, openSans in French.

Localization

```
arrayOfTitle = [NSLocalizedString("comment", comment: "0"), NSLocalizedString("profile", comment: "1"), NSLocalizedString("Like", comment: "2")]
```

patterns using String 1.

```
let username: String? = (rList[indexPath.row].userInfo?.name)!

let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: username!,
                                                   attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Roboto-Bold", size: 12.0)!])

attrString.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string: rList[indexPath.row].gender,
                                                    attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Roboto", size: 12.0)!]))

cell.label.attributedText = attrString
```

patterns using String 2.

```
 customButton.setTitle("edit", for: .normal)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, there you have 3 tasks to do.

1. Map font name with current language code
2. Get regular font from the name
3. Get bold font from the name (optionally, but spotted from your code)

#### 1. Map font name with current language code

In order to do that you need to get that code and write a switch statement.

It can look like this (may vary depending on your needs)

```swift
func languageCode() -> String? {
    return NSLocale.autoupdatingCurrent.languageCode
}

func localizedFontName() -> String {
    let defaultFont = "Arial"
    guard let code = languageCode() else {
        return defaultFont
    }
    switch(code) {
    case "en":
        return "Helvetica"
    case "fr":
        return "Menlo"
    default:
        return defaultFont
    }
}
```

Please refer to [NSLocale documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nslocale) for more info.

#### 2. Get regular font from the name

It can be achieved by using `UIFontDescriptor`

```swift
let DefaultFontSize: CGFloat = 12.0
func font(from name: String) -> UIFont {
    let descriptor = UIFontDescriptor(name: name, size: DefaultFontSize)
    return UIFont(descriptor: descriptor, size: DefaultFontSize)
}
```

#### 3. Get bold font from the name

And the last task can be done via `UIFontDescriptor` as well.

```swift
let BoldFontSize: CGFloat = 12.0
func boldFont(from name: String) -> UIFont {
    let regularFont = font(from: name)
    guard let descriptor = regularFont.fontDescriptor
                                      .withSymbolicTraits(.traitBold) else {
        return regularFont
    }
    return UIFont(descriptor: descriptor, size: BoldFontSize)
}
```

Ultimately it all can be used like this:

```
let nameFont = boldFont(from: localizedFontName())
let nameString = NSAttributedString(string: "username ",
                                    attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: nameFont])

let surnameFont = font(from: localizedFontName())
let surnameString = NSAttributedString(string: "gender",
                                       attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: surnameFont])
```

Complete Playground can be found here [playground.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z8ejo9cyudoazpq/LocaleAwareFont.playground.zip?dl=1)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thans for your kind answer!