# localizing ios application with longer strings

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization

I need to localize my iOS application, from EN (English) to FR (Francais). the problem - most of FR strings are much longer than EN strings, so if I use the same UI, it does not look well with FR strings

When localizing android application, I used different resource files for each language, with smaller font, larger height, etc. ...

What is equivalent iOS solution for longer strings in different language?

for changing the font size, I can use this solution: - [Swift3 different font in the All of the UIView with Localization each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43842029/swift3-different-font-in-the-all-of-the-uiview-with-localization-each)

Is there a simpler solution, in which I can see at design time how the screen is displayed?

Comment: You should be using dynamic font size for your labels - that will enable you to use the same UI regardless of localisation.

Answer (score 1):

You can fit texts into your views for all length using ***Auto Layout*** regardless of *Font, Language, Orientation, DeviceSize etc*.

There is a sample [blog post](http://www.ibabbleon.com/copywriter-translator/2017/01/use-auto-layout-xcode-localized-apps/) for some tips for that:

#### Tips for using Auto Layout when localizing apps

- **Remove all fixed-width constraints**. If the German text is 30% longer,
  and you don’t provide room for it in your UI, this will at least let
  iOS change the font size to accommodate. Otherwise, your localized
  text will get cropped.
- **Text fields should fit to contents**. Select **Editor** > **Size To Fit
  Content** so that text fields and labels resize automatically for
  longer or shorter text.
- **Pin views to adjacent views.** This way, when one view resizes to fit
  your localized text, the other views will too. Otherwise, views may
  overlap in some languages
- **No minimums or maximums**. Allow each content view to adjust in size as the language changes.
- **Use leading and trailing attributes instead of left and right**. This
  tip will make right-to-left languages (Arabic, Hebrew) flow properly.

You can also have look at [Introduction to Auto Layout](https://www.appcoda.com/learnswift/auto-layout-intro.html)

Comment: In such design limits, I cannot use "two coloumns" design, as my EN version uses now, because I cannot set the fixed-width

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code snippet to determine the language setting of a device:

```
Locale.current.languageCode
```

And than you can change/set the font size accordingly